# how can I sort the array according to particular element of multiple lists?

Tags: python

I have been trying to sort the array according to the last element of each list (2.8,3.5,1.9,3.6,1.0) but whenever I am using sorted functions it is just sorting the array according to its first element.

```
arr = np.array([[2,1,4,5,2.8],[1,9,3,2,3.5],[3,1,1,2,1.9],[2,2,3,5,3.6],[4,1,6,7,1.0]])
```

how can I sort the above array only on the basis of the last element of each list, such as;

[[4,1,6,7,**1.0**],[3,1,1,2,**1.9**],[2,1,4,5,**2.8**],[1,9,3,2,**3.5**],[2,2,3,5,**3.6**]]

Can you make it like the list I given you above?

Answer (score 1):

try using `argsort` by the last column:

```
idx=np.argsort(arr[:,-1])
sorted_arr = arr[idx]
```

---

**sorted_arr:**

```
array([[4. , 1. , 6. , 7. , 1. ],
       [3. , 1. , 1. , 2. , 1.9],
       [2. , 1. , 4. , 5. , 2.8],
       [1. , 9. , 3. , 2. , 3.5],
       [2. , 2. , 3. , 5. , 3.6]])
```

Comment: use `.tolist()` If you want to have in list format